# RUST/WASM threads in a browser

Tags: multithreading, rust, webassembly, web-worker

When a web app runs multi threaded WASM code (compiled from RUST), the web app will use web worker for the threads while RUST (compiled to native executables outside of the browser) is using native threads. Is there ever any impedance mismatch in the sense that that there are things it is easy/fast to do with native threads but not with web workers (hence the web app would not behave as expected)? For example, is it more lightweight to spawn native threads while web threads must be used more sparingly? Is passing arguments to WASM thread more expensive? Any hard limits on WASM threads (number of threads, input size etc)?

Comment: To be clear, when you say "Rust", do you mean "Rust compiled to native executables outside of the browser"?

Comment: yes, edited the question to clarify this